# LUA, something like pointer to variable

Tags: pointers, lua

I have function who send data via UART- they need one byte for data and address to store in target device. I cannot call this function direct, so I have function who place this data to queue. Now I want to check that data are write by uart correct so I think that the best way is read it direct after send and use pointer to variable instead variable. Problem is that LUA not suport pointer like in C because here everything is a pointer (if I understand good). So, how to give function in LUA "pointer" and read/write variable by thier address in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Tables are Lua's reference type (apart from userdata, which can not be used well from pure Lua - you need a C part to make use of it). You can trivially implement "pointers" using tables `{value = ...}`:

```lua
local function work_with_pointer(pointer)
    pointer.value = 42
end

local pointer = {value = 33}

work_with_pointer(pointer)

print(pointer.value) -- 42
```

That said, this is not very idiomatic Lua in its current state - ideally you'd return the changed value instead - but for a more complex "pointer" (table) it might be; in this case, simply using an upvalue would suffice as well:

```
local value = 33

local function work_with_upvalue()
    value = 42
end

work_with_upvalue()

print(value) -- 42
```

this has the limitation that it requires the function to be in the lexical scope of the variable however.